# htaccess to redirect subdomains to a different URL with the subdomain info

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

With .htaccess files I need to take any URL as long as it has a non-www subdomain and redirect it to a different structure:

`test.example.com -> example.com/r/test`

`another.example.com/foo/bar -> example.com/r/another`

`sub.example.com/q -> example.com/r/sub`

`www.example.com -> www.example.com`

I've gotten close, but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rules in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /r/%1 [L]
```

This should rewrite `foobar.example.com` to `example.com/r/foobar` . The redirection is internal meaning that your browser URL won't change . You can use `R=301` in your rule if you are looking for an external 301 redirection of URLs.

Comment: Missing the url on the rewriterule, but after adding, it works, thank you!